# Ubuntu 16.04 with CPU Intel i5 randomly unresponsive

Tags: 16.04, performance, cpu

I have built a mini-itx with an Intel i5 CPU. I have set up Ubuntu 16.04.

Everything was running fine until a week ago. Since then the PC has been randomly unresponsive and only starts working again after a power cycle.

What could be the problem and how can I fix it?